# Nested in object array destructuring with assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object:

```
let obj = { rows: [1, 2] }
```

How can I do ES6 array destructuring with assignment for value `1`?

For the array itself I can do like that, but I don't know how to get the first value:

```
let {rows: [first] } = obj

first // 1
```

Sorry, all is working in my example, was confused by error in my console.log test

Comment: `b` is `1` there, **not** `[1,2]`.

Comment: Format your question properly please. That's not even a valid object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ehh, sory my mistake, didn't see second console.log in my code :/

Comment: What output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get first value of array then use the code below.

```js
const data ={
 rows:[1,2,3]
}
let {rows:[first]} = data;
console.log(first)
```